# How to choose Firebase "Cloud Storage Location"?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am from Bangladesh. I try to make an android app where images are stored at firebase storage. Now I have to choose "Cloud Storage Location". I don't understand which location is better for me.. **Default(nam5 Us-central) or asia-south1 or any other region??**

[image: Cloud Storage Location]

Can you please tell me which location is better and why ??

Comment: You should benchmark that to see which one is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asia-south1` is the region of `Mumbai`
Which is nearest to `Bangladesh` 
So, you can go with it.

> **Cloud Storage Regions:** https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/locations